# Does a contractible set have contractible preimage, under a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear map of vector spaces, and let $A\subset W$ be contractible. Then is $T^{-1}(A)$ also contractible?

Comment: What if $W$ has dimension $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $T$ is not onto, this is not true. Consider the embedding $T \colon \def\R{\mathbf R}\R \cong \R \times \{0\} \to \mathbf R^2$, and the subset $A := \{x \in \mathbf R^2: x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 1, x_2 \ge 0\}$, the upper half of $S^1$. Then $A$ is contractible, but $T^{-1}[A] = \{(1,0), (-1,0)\}$ is not.

On the other hand, if $T$ is onto, this is true: Choose a complement $V'$ of $\ker T$, that is $V = V' \oplus \ker T$. Then $T|_{V'} \colon V' \to W$ is an isomorphism $A' := T^{-1}[A] \cap V'$ is homeomorphic to $A$ and hence contractible. We will show that $T^{-1}[A]$ deformation retracts to $T^{-1}[A]\cap V'$ and the result follows. Define $H \colon T^{-1}[A] \times I \to T^{-1}[A]$ by $$ 
H\bigl((v',v''), t\bigr) = \bigl(v', (1-t)v''\bigr), \qquad (v',v'') \in T^{-1}[A] \subseteq V = V' \oplus \ker T $$
Then $H$ is continuous, $H(\cdot,0)$ is the identity and $H(\cdot, 1)$ a retraction to $A'$. Hence, we are done.